# .scss not updating style in MVC project

Tags: model-view-controller, sass

I've searched this question but cant fnd the right question I'm asking about.

I have an MVC project and there's some auto-generated css files that I dont use. 
I have a scss folder with a file a .scss file called _main-style.scss.

I have a another file that references these sheets, and I use

@import 'sections/main-style';

I'm following the same naming convention as the others.

I even right clicked and did compile. 
When I run on the browser, it still doesnt update. I inspect the element and the classes dont exist. It's like its not getting them at all.

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it needed a hard refresh

Answer (score 0):

From your description, seems like you know about scss and how to compile it to css.

> I have an MVC project and there's some auto-generated css files that I dont use.

**BUT**, What do you mean by this?

Normally if you compile scss to css, and if that css is already linked with your document, It should update automatically

Comment: I thought they were automatic css files in the project but I was wrong. ignore that.

I dont understand though because I've added the classes in scss, complied, built, save. everything. I check the css file. It is there. I run in browser. Styles not affected. I inspect element and the styles are not added in the css. It has not updating. I dont understand why?

Comment: There must be a problem with CSS linking path. Make sure you are linking new CSS files that are generated from your scss